# vtktriangle compute normal from arbitrary points with python

Tags: python-2.7, vtk

I am using python wrappings for VTK. I want my script to let the user pick three arbitrary points and return a triangle with its normal information. In VTK [VTK Triangle](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkTriangle.html) reference there is vtkTriangle::ComputeNormal     (double v1[3], double v2[3],double v3[3],double n[3]). 
I checked Cxx implementation examples about vtkTriangle but, I don't understand how to implement this in Python. Does n[3] stand for the normal? If so what it should be as an input parameter?

@g.stevo I understand that. However, when I give a random value the method ComputeNormal returns None. To be more clear you can find the snippet of related code below:

```
`p0 = trianglePolyData.GetPoints().GetPoint(0)
 p1 = trianglePolyData.GetPoints().GetPoint(1)
 p2 = trianglePolyData.GetPoints().GetPoint(2)
 print vtk.vtkTriangle().TriangleArea(p0,p1,p2)
 n=[0.0,0.0,0.0]
 print vtk.vtkTriangle().ComputeNormal(p0,p1,p2,n)`
```

Comment: Which python wrappings are you using?

Comment: Hi Stephen,  I am using the current VTK-7.1.0 release,  compiled with cmake and MS VS 2015 for win 10 64 bit.

Comment: n[3] is an array in which the normals are written to - so any input doesn't matter. See Line 213 of vtkTriangle.h http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/5.0/html/a03658.html#l00219

Comment: @g.stevo I included the relevant code. However ComputeNormal returns None. Could you tell me why it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working. The result you are looking for is in the array n. The function ComputeNormal returns void, according to the [documentation](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkTriangle.html#a1fb18b46ba1844db68cdc4ddb0f13fe7).

Try this:

```
n=[0.0,0.0,0.0]
vtk.vtkTriangle().ComputeNormal(p0,p1,p2,n)
print n
```

Comment: Obviously, I was burned out to see that! Thanks.